# How to translate a boost based timer into Unix based (boost date_time free) class?

Tags: c++, unix, boost

So I am new to Unix and do not know its API's. I wonder what are mirror apis on Unix?

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

class timer
{
public:
        timer();
        void restart();
        boost::posix_time::time_duration elapsed() const;
private:
        boost::posix_time::ptime start_time;
};

// and cpp looks like
#include "timer.h"

timer::timer() : start_time(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()) { }

void timer::restart()
{
        start_time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
}

boost::posix_time::time_duration timer::elapsed() const
{
        return boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() - start_time;
}
```

So how to remove boost use in my simple class using Unix api's?

Comment: Why not continue to use Boost?

Comment: it appeares not all Unix editions are friendly with Boost Date_Time

Answer (score 0):

Unix time is number of seconds passed from an epoch(1970-01-01T00:00:00Z), you already know the rest of it:

```
using boost::posix_time;
ptime unixEpoch( 1970, 1, 1 );
time_t t = (time_t) (microsec_clock::local_time() - unixEpoch).total_seconds()
```